# How to Systematically Play Multiple Sounds using a UIButton?

Tags: swift, audio, uibutton, avaudioplayer

I am attempting to make a UIButton that will systematically play 4 sounds in a specific order, each one after pressing the UIButton. I tried doing this by using the code:

```
var counter = 0

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        counter = counter + 1


        if counter == 1 {
            print("play 1_barbradycarryon.wav")
        }else if counter == 2{
            print("play 2_fooledyou.wav")
        }else if counter == 3 {
            print("play 3_Looney.wav" )
        }else if counter == 4 {
            print("play 4_sucks.wav")
        }
    }
```

But I had no luck.  What code should I use? And, if needed, how should I insert AVAudioPlayer into the script (So far, I did not insert AVAudioPlayer; mostly because I do not know how in this scenario)? 
I am a new coder and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Only I need to have the button systematically play 4 sounds.

Comment: So why not apply the existing example to your code or vice versa?